# Working With Filters in Crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I have just started working with crossfilter and d3.js ... I'm trying some snippets given in the API reference... I Have the following data

```
var payments = crossfilter([
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
]);
```

I can create dimension via type as

```
var paymentsByTotal = payments.dimension(function(d) { return d.type; });
```

My question is that how can i filter an array of strings. I tried:

```
paymentsByTotal.filterRange(["cash","visa"]);
```

But I didn't get the expected result!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the sourcecode in the master branch of Crossfilter.js, there is no provision for union of filters, you have to get the code from [Jason Davies' union branch](https://raw.github.com/jasondavies/crossfilter/5e2518fee8a2a48bc120f6d6ff5921659dbad975/crossfilter.js).

Then, you should be able to do `paymentsByTotal.filter("cash","visa");` and get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Appears that a `filterFunction(function)` has been added since the previous response, so that you can now do this with:

```
paymentsByTotal.filterFunction(function(d) { return d === "visa" || d === "cash" });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of values, and you don't want to specify the explicit logic (i.e. `d === "visa"` ) for each item, then you can extend sai's `filterFunction` solution to check if the value is included in your array. Doing it this way just makes things easier if your array of items to filter is large or likely to change.

```
var items = ['Visa', 'Cash'];
paymentsByTotal.filterFunction(function(d) { return items.indexOf(d) > -1;});
```